# Timepicker in a dropdown menu is not working on iPad and touch devices

Tags: ios, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ipad, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have used the following code to create a timepicker in my app:
http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/
But, this doesn't open a pop-up timer on iPad and touch devices. What's the issue?

HTML:

```html
<div class="btn-group" dropdown dropdown-append-to-body id="ddlETA">
 <div id="btn-append-to-body" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"   dropdown-toggle
 tabindex="4"
    ng-click="vm.showETA()"
    title="ETA"
 >
   ETA<span class="caret"
  ></span>
 </div>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body"
   
 >
  <li role="menuitem">
   <a href="" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">Start Time
    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
     <input type="text" id="timepicker1" class="form-control input-small" placeholder="" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2"
     ng-model="vm.startTime"
     ng-change="vm.getETACount('time')
     />
     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
    </div>
   </a>
  </li>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
   /*$("#timepicker1").on("click", function(e){
    $('#timepicker1').timepicker();
    e.stopPropagation();
   });*/
   $('#timepicker1').timepicker();
   $('#timepicker2').timepicker();
  </script>
 </ul>
</div>
```

my bower.json:

```css
"bootstrap-3-timepicker": "~0.2.8",
    "bootstrap-toggle": "~2.2.0",
    "bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker": "~1.2.1",
    "es5-shim": "~3.1.0",
    "jquery": "~1.11.2",
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `showClose: true`to your timePicker. It at least sorts out the issue on IOS